# Multiple times view execution

Tags: jquery, sql, hive, hiveql

I am working on large dataset, I need to optimize the query. I have a view abc_view. Below query view is used 4 times. So every time view is executed, it contains complex logic. How can I build the query that view will execute only one time.

```
    Select * from TableA a
    join abc_view v on(a.col1=v.line)
    where v.type='abc' 
union all
    Select * from TableA a
    join abc_view v on(a.col1=v.group)
    where v.type='bcd'
union all
    Select * from TableA a
    join abc_view v on(a.col1=v.cat)
    where v.type='cde'
union all
    Select * from TableA a
    join abc_view v on(a.col1=v.test)
    where v.type='def'
```

query take around 5min to execute. What I thought that I have to create  a table from abc_view view and use that table in query to optimize it or something as?

suggest me the optimize query.

Comment: Maybe create a temporary table so you can add indexeson all the columns that you join with.

Comment: Remove UNION ALL and use one temporary table to store each query data and then select data from that temporary table and make it stored procedure and it will call every time but still faster than above method.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that a single reference to the view would improve performance, but not guaranteed.  In standard SQL, you could do:

```
Select *
from TableA a join
     abc_view v
     on (a.col1 = v.line and v.type = 'abc' ) or
        (a.col1 = v.group and v.type = 'bcd' ) or
        (a.col1 = v.cat and v.type = 'cde' ) or
        (a.col1 = v.test and v.type = 'def' );
```

However, Hive will probably reject this.

I'm not sure if Hive materializes CTEs.  If so, this might solve your problem:

```
 with v as (select * from abc_view)
 Select *
 from TableA a join
      v
      on( a.col1 = v.line
 where v.type='abc' 
 union all
 Select *
 from TableA a join
      v
     on a.col1 = v.group
     where v.type = 'bcd'
 union all
 Select *
 from TableA a join
      v
      on a.col1 = v.cat
 where v.type = 'cde'
 union all
 Select *
 from TableA a join
      v
      on a.col1 = v.test
 where v.type = 'def';
```

If not, you might have to use a temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it will perform well

```
SELECT * FROM TableA a
JOIN abc_view v ON a.col1 IN (v.line, v.group, v.cat, v.test)
    AND v.type IN ('abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'def')
```

and index on a.col1 and all four of view (v.line, v.group, v.cat, v.test)